# Need to change field value from blank to "Unknown" in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to replace all blank records within a query with "Unknown"

Tried setting the default value to "Unknown" but that did not work

Desired outcome:

"Blank" Records -> "Unknown" Records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created an update query to replace Null values with "Unknown"

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIF and Isnull to default null values to unknown - e.g.

```
select iif(isnull(field1), 'Unknown', field1), 
iif(isnull(field2), 'Unknown', field2) from table1
```

(effectively saying if field1 is null return Unknown, otherwise return field 1)